# Objective-c AES encryption doesn't look like java AES encryption

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, encryption, aes

Well im trying to encrypt an string in objective c extending NSData with this method:

```
 @implementation NSData (AES128)
```

- (NSData *)AES128Encrypt {
  char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = {'\xe1','\xaa','\x9c','\x61','\x46','\x74','\x44','\x56','\xf0','\xe5','\x47','\x46','\x86','\xdc','\x95','\x77'};

  NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

  size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
  void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

  size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
  CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,keyPtr,kCCKeySizeAES128,NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,[self bytes], dataLength, /* input */buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
          &numBytesEncrypted);
  if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
  //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
  return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
  }

  free(buffer); //free the buffer;
  return nil;
  }
- (NSData *)AES128Decrypt {
  char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = {'\xe1','\xaa','\x9c','\x61','\x46','\x74','\x44','\x56','\xf0','\xe5','\x47','\x46','\x86','\xdc','\x95','\x77'};

  NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

  //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
  //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
  //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
  size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
  void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

  size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
  CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus=CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,[self bytes], dataLength, /* input */buffer, bufferSize, /* output */&numBytesDecrypted);

  if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
  //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
  return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
  }

  free(buffer); //free the buffer;
  return nil;
  }

@end

then i call it here:

```
NSString *strData = @"My string";
```

NSData *objNSData = [NSData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"encrypted: %@",[objNSData description]);

If I just use it in objective c, it works fine.
But when i try to send it to a java server it doesn't work.

My cipher data seems like this:

86fcf0fa9e3dff93dc8918ffd02ee203 12de0bf8c8ba300456293c4240296c0d

and if I try to cipher it in java using also AES with the same key, i get this:

86fcf0fa9e3dff93dc8918ffd02ee203 8388f173da143c6aeeb90e554259c83c

its weird because the first half its the same.

Someone knows why this can be happening? 
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never done any Objective-C programming, but I'm almost positive that you're using AES in different [modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) in your code. You need to make sure these are consistent. The default is probably [Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) mode. Make sure you set this option in your Java code.

By the way, CBC mode should have a randomized Initialization Vector (IV) rather than NULL (which I assume uses all zeros). This too would need to be consistent across both.

I'm obliged to give standard disclaimer with cryptography that it's usually much safer to use a higher level protocol that handles this stuff for you like SSL/TLS for data in transit and something like [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) for data at rest. Getting crypto right is really hard and a tiny error (like picking a bad mode) can totally destroy the security of the system.

Comment: man I love you :) actually the problem was i was passing just the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding option to the CCCrypt function where i have to pass kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode option anyway thanks, your answer saved my day :)

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that as I mentioned before, you really shouldn't use ECB mode. If at all possible use something like CBC. See Act 3, Scene 21 of http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html (direct link: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Zfbv3mHcYrc/SrfI0ckVcMI/AAAAAAAABss/wUh6hWmtNaU/s1600-h/aes_act_3_scene_21_modes_1100.png )

Comment: the problem is that ECB mode seems to be the only way supported in obj-c

Comment: According to http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h , the default (if you don't specify a mode) is CBC. I'd use that. "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding" is fine to use as well. Just make sure you do the same on the Java side. Additionally, you should be using a randomized initialization vector (the Java side will need to know this too)